Expected hitting time in at least one walk with multiple 1-side bounded simple random walks
Let $S_n^1,\dots,S^d_n$ be $d$ mutually independent simple one-dimensional random walks on $\mathbb{Z}$ with $x=S_0^1=\dots=S_0^d$. In each time step each of the $d$ random walks moves, independently of the others, either $+1$ or $-1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Let $T_x$ denote the number of steps before at least one of the $d$ random walks hits $0$ for the first time. What is $E(T_x)$?
For $d=1$ this becomes the standard one-dimensional random walk and thus $E(T_x)=\infty$ even for $x=1$. If $d$ were infinite one could argue that after $x$ steps infinitely many random walks would have a.s. taken $-1$ step $x$-times and thus $E(T_x)=x$. What can we tell about $E(T_x)$ for finite $d\geq 2$?

First, assume that instead of a random walk you have a Brownian motion.
Then
$$
E[T_x] = \int_0^\infty P(T_x \geq t)
$$
and
$$
P(T_x \geq t) \\
= \prod_i P( \sup_{s \in [0, t]} S_s^i < x_i ) \\
= \prod_i P(|S_t^i| < x_i ) \quad \text{ (reflection principle)}\\
= \prod_i P( |X| < x_i/\sqrt{t}) \quad (S_t^i \sim \sqrt{t} X))\\
\sim \frac{2^d}{\sqrt{2\pi t}^d} \prod_i x_i \quad \text{ (for large t) }
$$
where $X$ has a standard normal distribution.
This shows that $E[T_x] < \infty$ if and only if $d \geq 3$.
To adapt this proof to the case of a discrete random walk, you must use the discrete reflection principle
$$
P(\sup_{s \in [0, t]} S_s \geq x) = P(S_t \geq x) + P(S_t \geq x + 1)
$$
and prove the large-$t$ asymptotics in the last step of the displayed equation above via Stirling's formula.
By the way, for a Brownian motion, you can show
$$
E[T_x] = \|x\|_2^2 E[T_{x / \|x\|_2}]
$$
via a scaling argument.
For a discrete random walk, you can imagine that the same scaling must be true for large $x$ because the random walk looks more and more like a Brownian motion at large scales.

$\mathbb{E}[T_{d,x}]$ is finite if and only if $d \geq 3$. I don't know whether there is a simple argument for this but I can offer you the brute force computation below. As a by-product the computation gives formulas for $\mathbb{E}[T_{d,x}]$ in terms of values of hypergeometric functions.
For $t \geq x \geq 1$ let $N_{x,t}$ be the number of walks of length $t$ that start at $x$ and hit 0 for the first time after the last step. From the recursion $N_{x,t} = N_{x+1,t-1} + N_{x-1,t-1}$ and the appropriate boundary conditions it follows that the non-zero values are
$$ N_{x,x+2n} = \frac{x}{x+n} \binom{2n+x-1}{n} \, . $$
The probability that a random walk starting at $x$ hits 0 for the first time after $x+2n$ steps is then given by
$$ \mathbb{P}_x(T = x+2n) = \frac{N_{x,x+2n}}{2^{x+2n}} \, . $$
Similarly, the probability that a random walk starting at $x$ did not hit 0 after $x+2n$ steps is given by
$$ 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}_x(T > x+2n) &= 1 - \sum_{k=0}^n  \, \mathbb{P}_x(T = x+2k) \\
&= \frac{1}{2^{2+2n+x}}\binom{2n+1+x}{n+1} \frac{x}{n+1+x} R_x(n)
\end{align*} 
$$
with
$$ R_x(n) = {}_3F_2(1,1+n+\tfrac{x}{2},\tfrac{3}{2}+n+\tfrac{x}{2};2+n,2+n+x;1) \, .$$
The recursion $ \mathbb{P}_x(T > x+2n) = \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}_{x+1}(T > x+2n-1) + \frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}_{x-1}(T > x+2n-1)$ implies that the rational functions $R_x$ satisfy the recursion
$$ R_x(n) = \frac{x-1}{x} \frac{2n+2+x}{n+2}R_{x-1}(n+1) - \frac{x-2}{x} \frac{n+1+x}{n+2}R_{x-2}(n+1) \, . $$
For the first few $x$ we have
$$ 
\begin{align*}
R_1(n) &= 2n+4\\
R_2(n) &= 2n+6\\
R_3(n) &= \frac{6n^2+38n+56}{3(n+2)}\\
\end{align*}
$$
and in particular $R_x(n) = 2n+O(1)$. Writing
$$ 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[T_{d,x}] &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (x+2n) \, (\mathbb{P}_x(T \geq x+2n)^d - \mathbb{P}_x(T > x+2n)^d) \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (x+2n) \, \sum_{i=1}^d \binom{d}{i} \, \mathbb{P}_x(T = x+2n)^i \, \mathbb{P}_x(T > x+2n)^{d-i} 
\end{align*}
$$
and using Stirling's formula $n! = \sqrt{2\pi n} \, (\tfrac{n}{e})^n \, (1+O(1/n))$ we find that $\mathbb{E}[T_{d,x}]$ is finite if and only if $n \cdot \frac{1}{n^{3/2}} \cdot (\frac{1}{n^{1/2}})^{d-1}$ goes to zero faster than $1/n$ and hence $d>2$.
The formulas above also allow to express $\mathbb{E}[T_{d,x}]$ in terms of values of hypergeometric functions. For example one finds that
$$ 
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[T_{3,1}] =& -1 \\
&+ {}_3F_2(-\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{2};1,1;1) \\
&-3 \, {}_3F_2(-\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};1,1;1) \\
&+3 \, {}_3F_2(-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};1,1;1) \\
&+\tfrac{1}{4} \, {}_3F_2(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2};2,2;1) \\
&+\tfrac{3}{4} \, {}_3F_2(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{3}{2};2,2;1) \\
&+\tfrac{3}{4} \, {}_3F_2(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{3}{2},\tfrac{3}{2};2,2;1) \\
=& 1.78640785937135\cdots \, .
\end{align*}
$$

I am unfamiliar with hypergeometric functions, so it might take me a while to understand what is going on here, but I wonder, does this only show that $E(T_x)$ is finite for $d>2$ or does it also tell us how large it is? I have a completely different proof that if $d>2$ then $E(T_x)=O(n^{2+\epsilon})$ for each $\epsilon>0$, as well as  $E(T_x)=\Omega(n^{2})$.

Don't worry too much about the hypergeometric functions. Here I really just use them to give names to the associated infinite sums. I can imagine you can get your growth conditions from my formulas, but it might be a bit tedious. Would you mind sharing your proof?
